# ThreeJS my GLTF loading speed is too slow on host server?

Tags: javascript, three.js, loading, gltf

I'm currently creating a Website with a 3D Market Place feature in it. Alas, I'm having trouble implementing the main feature of this website.

This is the website (alpha state): https://www.openstring-studios.com/

All the code is in the index.html file there so you can see how it's made, don't mind the mess though, my issue is only with the loading of 3D models into the scene.

There is this website called sketchfab.com and they have this amazing feature of previewing PBR Assets within a WebGL Window. And it loads reasonably fast.

Here's my problem. I want to create a similar feature for my website and got the ThreeJS Library to do it. However, even though everything loads quite quickly on my xampp localhost as soon as I upload it on my host server, the models take forever to load (probably because of the 4k textures).

This is the code I use:

```
function init() {   
    camera.position.z = 0.3;
    camera.position.y = 0.15;
    camera.position.x = 0.4;
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/sceenDivide, 600 );
    renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.gammaFactor = 2.8;

    new THREE.RGBELoader().setDataType( THREE.UnsignedByteType )
    .setPath( '' ).load( 'white_cliff_top_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {   
        var cubeGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: 512 } );
        var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( cubeGenerator.renderTarget.texture );
        var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
        envMap = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget.texture;
        cubeGenerator.update( renderer );
        pmremGenerator.update( renderer );
        pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );
        loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( '' );
        loadModel( 'Promo_ProductSoil.gltf');
        loadModel( 'Promo_ProductCover.gltf');
        loadModel( 'StraightPot_OrangePaintedIron.gltf');
        pmremGenerator.dispose();
        pmremCubeUVPacker.dispose();
        scene.background = cubeGenerator.renderTarget;
    } );
}

function loadModel( src ) {
    loader.load( src , function ( gltf ) {
        gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child.isMesh ) {

                child.material.envMap = envMap;
                child.position.y -= 0.12
                mesh = child;                   
            }
            gltfSource = gltf;
        } );
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        onProgress( xhr )
    } );
}
```

Is there a solution how I can achieve a similar loading speed as seen on the website sketchfab.com because at the moment my simple pot model takes over a minute before it is displayed.

The only reason why the planes load so fast is that their material has only a low-resolution BaseColor and nothing else.

Any ideas on how to solve this. My website is hosted through domain.com, should I ask them or is it more a ThreeJS issue and if so are there alternatives?

Comment: This is purely a file size issue. You will need to use smaller files for your assets (if your texture is large then you **must** use smaller texture).

Comment: To actually get results like sketchfab will require making your own file format. Sketchfab loads low-poly models, and low-res textures. Then streams high poly models and higher resolution textures. They support more features than glTF and they likely have a custom asset conditioning pipeline that takes users assets and processes them into the a better format for displaying in a webpage possibly doing things like automatically making texture atlases as well as low-res textures and low poly models so users don't have to do that manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a solution how I can achieve a similar loading speed as seen on the website sketchfab.com because at the moment my simple pot model takes over a minute before it is displayed.

As mentioned in the comments, your `glTF` assets are just too big. E.g. `StraightPot_OrangePaintedIron.gltf` has file size of 41 MB. There are several way in order to speed up transmission time.

- You can compress the geometry data of your assets with DRACO and use `THREE.DRACOLoader` in combination with `THREE.GLTFLoader` to decompress the asset on the client side. The following [live example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf_extensions) demonstrates the usage of both loaders. Use a tool like [glTF Pipeline](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline) to compress existing `glTF` assets.
- Reduce the resolution of your textures. Also consider to use texture compression to further reduce the file size. However, it's still a bit inconvenient to use platform independent texture compression with WebGL. [Basis](https://www.khronos.org/blog/google-and-binomial-contribute-basis-universal-texture-format-to-khronos-gltf-3d-transmission-open-standard) will probably make things easier in the future.
- Reduce the complexity of your asset in general by simplifying the geometry. Sometimes it's also possible to lower the amount of materials and to merge the respective textures.

`three.js R108`

Comment: Thanks! I've tested importing draco compressed high-poly models and it really makes a big difference. I'll also try out the Basis demo, maybe it will work out after all. I've got some other problems with loading the textures at the moment, the UVs seem broken and my export / import pipeline seems to be messed up.. I've got to troubleshoot that first. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is actually an issue with draco and uvs in `R108`, see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17426.